# expresion regular extraer texto entre tags

Tags: php

Buenas estoy intentando obtener lo que se encuentra entre los tags `<!--producto--><!--endproduct-->`

```
$texto = <<<str
<!--product:id15-->
-Producto: Lentes C1
    -Marca: 'Traffic'
    -Color: 'Red'
<!--end-->
str;
```

he intentado hacerlo con expresiones regulares:

```
preg_match('/<!--product:(.+?)-->[\s\S](.+)[\s\S]*<!--endproduct-->.*/', $texto, $match);
```

pero me obtiene todo el texto hasta los tags de comentarios solo quiero el texto que se encuentra dentro

```
-Producto: Lentes C1
    -Marca: 'Traffic'
    -Color: 'Red'
```

Comment: No es mucho mas simple con funciones de string directamente? eso es una cadena?

Comment: {(?<=<!--product:[\w]{4}--\>)[\s\w]+(?=<!--end-->)} Con cuidado, con este, la id del producto tiene que ser 4 caracteres.  Y para encontrar los otros tags, tiene que modificar el regex {[\s\w]}  No es perfecto, pero es un lugar para empezar.

Comment: @gbianchi lo hice tambien mediante funciones separando el texto extraido por lineas con preg_split luego con un foreach verifico en que linea se encuentra el tags y guardo el numero de la linea para luego con un array_splice extraer el resultado pero es mucho procedimiento con una expresion regular seria suficiente "creo" pero no encuentro la menera de hacerla andar tu que propones